# Using custom camera shutter sound

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

Is there a way to implement custom shutter sound when capturing still image in camera controller? I guess default sound plays automatically and can't be turned off but is it ok to play another sound over it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

use this:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1108);
```

You can check all full sounds here:

[Sounds](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices)

For a custom sound:

```
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Name of your audio file" 
                                                      ofType:@"type of your audio file example: mp3"];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
[audioPlayer play];
```

Make sure you import

`<AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`

Comment: I am looking to play custom sound and not default one.